# 32 bit long vs 64 bit long

Tags: c++

I am working on project (c++ integration with Python) which has migrated to 32 bit machine to 64 bit machine. In Python, C long is mapped with Python Integer.
SO I can not change in Python Interface(client interface) and always gets overflow error from python client. it was working fine in 32 bit machine

So I have following solution

1)convert all long to int in 64 bit machine.

2)Declare 32 bit long in 64 bit machine.

Do we have any general solution/header file which give me option to declare 32 bit 
datatype always So I can handle this issue in more general way.

I know it may be small issue but I am not able to find general solution.

Comment: Just for the record, but Python's integral datatype is effectively variable-width, things like overflows are a non-issue there. Depending on the Python version, large numbers are represented with a different type, 2**1000 is long in Python 2 and int in later versions.

Comment: @doomster,After changing 32 bit also I still facing overflow error from Python interface.and they are using Python 2.7 . but it is crashing our application which we need to fix from our hand

Answer (score 4):

> Do we have any general solution/header file which give me option to declare 32 bit datatype always?

Yes, [there is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html), since C99.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t foo;
```

Comment: Thx for quick and proper responce

Answer (score 3):

standard C99 (and newer) has `<stdint.h>` header defining `int32_t` for 32 bits signed integers (and many other types) and recent C++ have `<cstdint>`

If you care about [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignums) (arbitrary precision numbers), be aware that it is a difficult subject and use some existing library, like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).